# Can I Create a Database and Tables in One SQL Command From PHP?

Tags: mysql, php

I tried separating the `CREATE DATABASE` and `CREATE TABLES` commands into different `mysqli_query` statements. The Database gets created but I get an error with:

```
$create_tables = "CREATE TABLE T2T_$grouporg.Memebers LIKE T2T_Main.Members; 
     CREATE TABLE T2T_$grouporg.Events LIKE T2T_Main.Events; 
     CREATE TABLE T2T_$grouporg.Taskers LIKE T2T_Main.Taskers";
     $creat_tables = mysqli_query($dbconnect,$create_tables) or 
     die("Create Table Error: " . mysqli_error($dbconnect) . 
     "<BR><BR><BR>" . $create_tables);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot execute multiple MySQL statements from PHP with `mysqli_query`, but you can with `mysqli_multi_query`!